# I/O error 530 when running crystal reports

Tags: dll, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

Since updating to Windows 10 1709, crystal reports appears to crash when selecting a report to run. It displays an I/O error : 530.

I have never seen this before, has anybody else come across this?, I've been looking online for further help but haven't really found anything.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was specific to certain manufacturers PCs, in this case - Dell. Preinstalled Dell software on the PCs was causing some sort of confliction. I uninstalled these software packages and it all appears to be working now.